# Segfault while running make modules_install

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I clone latest git tree from linux source. I am running all in Virtual box(first memory was 4096 MB because of seg-fault I increase to 8096 MB then also same error). Right now VM has 3.19.0 installed

```
>clone latest git tree
>make localmodconfig
>make -j1
>sudo make mosules_install

 All install work fine.
  but with depmod it's giving me below error

DEPMOD  4.3.0-11785-gca4ba96
depmod: WARNING: found 2 modules in dependency cycles!
depmod: WARNING: /lib/modules/4.3.0-11785-gca4ba96/kernel/drivers/staging/lustre/lnet/lnet/lnet.ko in dependency cycle!
depmod: WARNING: /lib/modules/4.3.0-11785-gca4ba96/kernel/drivers/staging/lustre/lustre/libcfs/libcfs.ko in dependency cycle!
./scripts/depmod.sh: line 57: 23221 Killed                  "$DEPMOD" "$@" "$KERNELRELEASE" $SYMBOL_PREFIX
make: *** [_modinst_post] Error 137
```

Earlier I got seg fault same line, this times it's killed because I tried depmod -a VERSION(4.3.0.....)

Also when I tried manually depmod -a VERSION(4.3.0.....) it's didn't gave me any error it's work fine.

Answer (score 1):

go to `libcfs/libcfs/module.c` and remove a switch-case piece for `IOC_LIBCFS_PING_TEST` - it's an obsolete codepiece, and it will work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue that hasn't been fixed yet, see lkml:
https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/11/7/229
To fix / work around it, disable the building of Lustre file system driver modules.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Commenting out the line of `"$DEPMOD" "$@" "$KERNELRELEASE" $SYMBOL_PREFIX` in file `scripts/depmod.sh` solved it.